# Mango seed growing, but not producing leaves

Tags: fruit-trees, houseplants, container-gardening

I planted a mango seed in a pot, after it germinated in a damp paper towel. It produced a stem, but has not done anything since for at least a month. Is it a faulty seed? Do I need to replant? Or is there something that can be done to rescue this seed? I live in Saskatchewan, so I realize that planting it outside is not an option, and it will likely never produce fruit.

Since this picture was taken in mid-March, the sprout has not grown at all. It still appears to be alive, but has not done anything. I believe it is getting sufficient sunlight. It sits in my window each day, and gets sunlight during the entire morning.

*<sub>Click on photo for full size</sub>*
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Camella; you can use the `edit` link underneath your post if you need to make updates to it. I took the liberty of including smaller versions of your photos with a click-through to the originals. I also added a couple of relevant tags.

Comment: FYI:Mango grown by a Seed will not have same characteristics as its parent. you could be better of planting a mango using a branch/cutting

Comment: Was that sprout growing tall or its the same after these days...

Comment: It has been the same ever since I posted the picture.

Comment: Have a lot of patience, a tree takes time to grow

Answer (score 1):

According to one person's experience on [this gardenweb thread](http://forums.gardenweb.com/forums/load/tropical/msg0418420213071.html) the sprout will get pretty tall before any leaves appear.

Answer (score 0):

I too have a mango seed I planted in the summer of 2014. It began to grow and sprouted 3 small leaves, but then stopped growing.  It survived the winter indoors and in the spring I returned it outdoors, but it still didn't grow. I thought perhaps there was a problem with the root system so I carefully unearthed it from the pot and saw that the root was more like a knotted stump. I thought maybe it was the soil, so I replanted it in a little larger pot with new soil. I sat back and watched and nothing happened after a week.

We had some rain and I thought I would let the rain do my watering and the next morning I couldn't believe my eyes! There was life from my little King Arthur (that's his name when I planted the seed). He began to grow from the top and life began to open for my little royal pal. I never gave up on him. You shouldn't either. It took over 9 months for him to grow.